# Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I was trying to build the below spark scala project using maven .The build was successful ,but when I ran that jar it is giving the below error.Please help me to fix

spark scala code

```
package com.spark.DataAnalysis

      import org.apache.log4j.Level
      import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
      import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TwitterData {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C://Sankha//Study//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example").setMaster("local[1]")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val csvData = sc.textFile("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\twitter-airline-sentiment\\Tweets.csv",3)
        val map_data = csvData.map(x=> x.split(",")).filter(x=> (x.length  < 13)).filter(x=> x(5) == "Virgin America")
        println(map_data.count())

  }
}
```

maven build code :

```
mvn package
```

Running the spark code from command line as below

```
spark-submit --class sparkWCExample.spWCExample.Twitter --master local[2] C:\Sankha\Study\spark_ws\spWCExample\target\spWCExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\Sankha\Study\spark_ws\spWCExample\target\out
```

Exception :

```
20/03/04 02:45:58 INFO Executor: Adding file:/C:/Users/sankh/AppData/Local/Temp/spark-ae5c0e2c-76f7-42d9-bd2a-6b1f5b191bd8/userFiles-ef86ac49-debf-4d19-b2e9-4f0c1cb83325/spWCExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to class loader
20/03/04 02:45:58 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: unexpected exception type
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.throwMiscException(ObjectStreamClass.java:1736)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1266)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2078)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda.readResolve(SerializedLambda.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1260)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
        at sparkWCExample.spWCExample.Twitter$.$deserializeLambda$(Twitter.scala)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LambdaDeserialize
        ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.LambdaDeserialize
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 72 more
```

Please advise

POM xml is as below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sparkWCExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>spWCExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spWCExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
 <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.3</version>
     </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Please check and let me know

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml here

Comment: I have updated pom xml above .Please advise now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be a few issues with your code and your POM.

Talking about the code, you have created a sparksession and a sparkcontext separately even though you can just create the SparkSession object and it has the sparkcontext present.
Also, you have set the spark properties in both your code and your spark-submit command. I recommend you create a separate sparkProperties file and pass it onto your spark-submit command (I'll share the file and the command too).

So, you can write the code as follows:

```
   package com.spark.DataAnalysis

      import org.apache.log4j.Level
      import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
      import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TwitterData {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C://Sankha//Study//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
        val csvData = .textFile("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\twitter-airline-sentiment\\Tweets.csv",3)
        val map_data = csvData.map(x=> x.split(",")).filter(x=> (x.length  < 13)).filter(x=> x(5) == "Virgin America")
        println(map_data.count())
        spark.close

  }
}
```

Now, coming to your pom.xml, you haven't added the maven-assembly-plugin and have just used the maven compiler plugin. This means that your code is compiled using the dependencies but the dependencies are not packaged in the jar. In this case, your scala dependency was not packaged and also not found in your system so it gave you an error. This is why it is always better to use maven assembly plugin.

So, your new pom.xml should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sparkWCExample</groupId>
<artifactId>spWCExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spWCExample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>

            <execution>
                <id>assemble-all</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

The sample properties file is as follows:

```
spark.master    local[2]
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.driver.memory     2G
spark.executor.memory   2G
spark.executor.instances        2
spark.executor.cores    2
spark.driver.maxResultSize      1g
```

Now, your spark-submit command will be much easier to write after adding the sparkProperties.properties file:

```
spark-submit --class sparkWCExample.spWCExample.Twitter C:\Sankha\Study\spark_ws\spWCExample\target\spWCExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar C:\Sankha\Study\spark_ws\spWCExample\target\out --properties-file sparkProperties.properties
```

I hope I have answered your question elaborately. Feel free to ask if you have any other doubts.

Comment: ERROR ShutdownHookManager: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: C:\Sankha\temp\spark-0463536d-891f-420e-b555-f8e42243e4f9\userFiles-165a61af-5484-4580-bc8e-c009816b076c
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\Sankha\temp\spark-0463536d-891f-420e-b555-f8e42243e4f9\userFiles-165a61af-5484-4580-bc8e-c009816b076c\spWCExample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: I tried your steps and it worked .Thank you .I am now only getting the below temp file delete error which is fine as I am getting the output before that .

Comment: I am new in Spark , so I might be contacting you again if I see other issues .Hope you will help me

Comment: Sure, you can reach out any time you want. And for the error listed above, you can try closing your SparkSession once you are done with the computations. This will ensure the freeing up of cluster resources for other applications. I've made the appropriate change in the code above. Tell me if this helps.

Comment: can you please help me for the below issues I am facing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567432/todf-is-not-working-in-spark-scala-ide-but-works-perfectly-in-spark-shell

Comment: @Siddharth Goel can you help and suggest how to handle this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036791/while-writing-to-hdfs-path-getting-error-java-io-ioexception-failed-to-rename