# toDF is not working in spark scala ide , but works perfectly in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and I am trying to run the below commands both from spark-shell and spark scala eclipse ide

When I ran it from shell , it perfectly works .

But in ide , it gives the compilation error.
Please help

```
    package sparkWCExample.spWCExample

    import org.apache.log4j.Level
    import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Dataset, SparkSession, DataFrame, Row }
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql._

    object TwitterDatawithDataset {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example")
            .setMaster("local[1]")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .config(conf)
            .appName("CsvExample")
            .master("local")
            .getOrCreate()
        val csvData = spark.sparkContext
            .textFile("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\bank_data.csv", 3)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
        case class Bank(age: Int, job: String)
        val bankDF = dfData.map(x => Bank(x(0).toInt, x(1)))
        val df = bankDF.toDF()
      }
    }
```

Exception is as below on compile time itself

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Bank]    TwitterDatawithDataset.scala    /spWCExample/src/main/java/sparkWCExample/spWCExample   line 35 Scala Problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To `toDF()`, you must enable implicit conversions:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
```

In `spark-shell`, it is enabled by default and that's why the code works there. `:imports` command can be used to see what imports are already present in your shell:

```
scala> :imports
 1) import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ (70 terms, 1 are implicit)
 2) import spark.implicits._       (1 types, 67 terms, 37 are implicit)
 3) import spark.sql               (1 terms)
 4) import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ (385 terms)
```

Comment: I did that as well , but stil getting exception ,I have updated my code above

Comment: @user1670805 your code  is not compilable because `new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` refers to undefined variable `sc`

Comment: how are you making dfData ? i cant see in the above code

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me in Eclipse Scala IDE:

```
case class Bank(age: Int, job: String)
val u = Array((1, "manager"), (2, "clerk"))
import spark.implicits._
spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(u).map(r => Bank(r._1, r._2)).toDF().show()
```